# Search result to show all subsites

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have created a page to show all subsites using below query for `content search webpart`

`path:"https://Testonline.sharepoint.com/sites/Test_System/"
path:"https://Testonline.sharepoint.com/sites/test/" contentclass:STS_Web Site<>{Site.URL} {SearchBoxQuery}`

This was able to bring all the subsites from both site collections, But suddenly I am not able to figure out what happend that it is only showing sites from only one site collection.

What could be the exact issue with it?

Comment: Try this tool to built query and test http://sp2013searchtool.codeplex.com/

Comment: i think you have to add an "OR" between the two path querys

Answer (score 2):

Few days ago I have done indexing to one of the site, So may be this was the issue that I have got sites from this site only.

So yesterday I indexed other site also and now this issue is fixed, now I can see the sub sites from both the sites.

Answer (score 0):

I got to see the same behavior with one of my result source.

- Make sure you haven't copy pasted these rules.
- Try to add these rules again from the query builder.
- Try changing position of these rules while adding

I would prefer to create a result source first and then use that in my search results. You can create a separate page for that result source as well.

Hope that helps.